# Cache manifest file needs to be saved twice

Tags: javascript, caching, refresh, manifest, offline

I've seen quite a few SO questions stating that you must reload your app twice in order to refresh files that appear within the Cache Manifest file.

I have something stranger going on: it seems that I need to SAVE my cache manifest twice before I cause a refresh.  If I save once then do many reloads I don't see the altered file.  If I save again then reload twice then I do see the changed file.

It's really weird.  I'm using Chrome, and the file in question is a .js file. My manifest file is as follows:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# V1.35

CACHE:

/Content/Site.css

/Scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js
/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.7.min.js
/Scripts/json2.js

/Scripts/mktpoint.sync.js
/Scripts/mktpoint.requestor.js
/Scripts/mktpoint.poster.js
/Scripts/mktpoint.profile.js
/Scripts/mktpoint.cache.js
/Scripts/mktpoint.helper.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Anyone know what's going on?  Thanks

EDIT: Further testing is showing that it all works fine when the site is running on IIS on a server.  The problem occurs in my Dev environment (VS2010).